# If a Killing vector field is timelike, can it be set to $\partial/\partial t$?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, vector-fields

If one has a Killing vector that turned out to be a timelike Killing vector field because of negative norm. Can we set this Killing vector field equal to $\partial/\partial t$?

Comment: Yes, you can choose the coordinates (locally) in that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Phoenix87 is spot on, but I'll elaborate a bit.

> **Definition 1** A spacetime $(M,g)$ is *stationary* if there exists a timelike Killing field $K$, i.e. a vector field $K$ such that $\langle K,K\rangle<0$ and $\mathcal{L}_Kg=0$.

We shall show that Definition 1 implies the existence of local coordinates for which $g_{\mu\nu}$ is independent of time.

Choose a spacelike hypersurface $\Sigma$ of $M$ and consider the integral curves of $K$ passing through $\Sigma$. In $\Sigma$ we choose arbitrary coordinates and introduce local coordinates of $M$ as follows: If $p=\phi_t(p_0)$, where $p_0\in\Sigma$ and $\phi_t$ is the flow of $K$, then the Lagrange coordinates of $p$ are $(t,\vec{x}(p_0))$. In terms of these coordinates, we have $$K=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$$ and $\mathcal{L}_Kg=0$ implies
$$\partial_tg_{\mu\nu}=0$$
We call such coordinates *adapted* to the Killing field.

Comment: Also, $K=-\partial/\partial t$ is consistent with the definition. Is the sign important somehow?

Comment: @apt45 Typically, we assume spacetime is *time-orientable* (i.e., there is a notion of the "future" time direction at each point), and we'd likely prefer to choose our $t$ coordinate such that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ is future-directed. This fixes the sign choice.

Answer (score 5):

The rough idea: take the local flow of the vector field and use it to get a new "time" coordinate. In general this will work *locally*, so you have to *patch* your manifold with small enough open subsets where you can then define the new set of coordinates where now the Killing vector field corresponds to $\partial_t$.

Answer (score 4):

Comments to the question (v3):

1. Given a manifold $M$, if a smooth vector field $X\in \Gamma(TM)$ does not vanish in a point $p\in M$, then one may choose a local coordinate neighborhood $U\subseteq M$ of $p$, with local coordinates $(x^1, \ldots, x^n)$, so that $X=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}$. This procedure is sometimes called *stratification* or [*straightening out*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straightening_theorem_for_vector_fields) of a vector field. It is a special case of [Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_%28differential_topology%29).
2. A timelike vector field $X$ does not vanish by definition, so it can be locally stratified $X=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}$, cf. 1. Since $X$ is timelike, one would call $x^1$ a time-coordinate.
3. The [Killing vector field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_vector_field) property is irrelevant for local stratification.

Comment: Is stratification the same as adaptation?

Comment: Possibly. Do you have a reference? I guess the notion of adaptation depends on context and author.